# sqlite3.programmingerror incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

Python 2.7 and sqlite3

I create a table like this:

```
#create table
connector.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable (
column1,
column2,
column3
''')
```

Then I iterate through a `.csv` file like this:

```
with open("mycsv.csv") as f:
for i in f:
    del splitted[:]
    del myData[:]
    splitted = i.split(",")
    for j in splitted:
        myData.append(tuple([j]))
```

which gives me this output:

```
print myData
> [('testtext1',), ('testtext2',), ('testtext3\n',)]
```

However, when I try to insert this into my `db` like so:

```
connector.executemany('''INSERT INTO mytable (
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
    ) VALUES (
    ?,?,?)''', myData)
```

I get the error

> sqlite3.programmingerror incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
>   current state uses 3, and tehre are 1 supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of 3 tuples, all containing 1 column each.

You want all 3 columns to make up the contents of 1 tuple.  Then you want to add that tuple to a list.  Try something like this:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable
             (column1 text, column2 text,column3 text)''')

myData = []
with open("mycsv.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        (col1, col2, col3) = line.split(',')
        mytuple = (col1, col2, col3)
        myData.append(mytuple)

cur.executemany('INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?,?,?)', myData)

for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable'):
    print row
```

Output:

```
(csv2sqlite)macbook:csv2sqlite joeyoung$ python csv2sqlite.py 
(u'testtext1', u'testtext2', u'testtext3')
(u'testtext1', u'testtext2', u'testtext3')
(u'testtext1', u'testtext2', u'testtext3')
```

Input:

```
(csv2sqlite)macbook:csv2sqlite joeyoung$ cat mycsv.csv 
testtext1,testtext2,testtext3
testtext1,testtext2,testtext3
testtext1,testtext2,testtext3
```